# Refactor code to create a table using a function

Tags: r, function, kable

I have a dataset showing the distribution of variables between 2 studies.

```
library(knitr)
library(IRdisplay)
library(tidyr)
treat<- c(0,1,1,1,1,1) study<- c(0,1,0,0,0,0)
age<-c(38.07647, 35.30403, 42.19468, 28.72244, 38.84273, 28.74006)
measure<- c(36.36798, 51.21708, 37.71801, 38.84021, 26.70908, 36.39133)
df<- data.frame(treat,study,age,measure)
```

The goal is to recreate this table:

[image]

I have code below and was able to create the table but is there a way to refactor it to make it shorter/more readable? I'd like to add a **function {}** ideally but I'm not sure how to go about doing that for this code. This is what I wrote to recreate the table:

```
a<-df%>%
filter(study==0)%>%
summarise(study0=paste(round(mean(age),3), '(', round(sd(age),3),')', sep=""))

b<- df%>%
filter(study==1)%>%
summarise(study1=paste(round(mean(age),3), '(', round(sd(age),3),')', sep=""))

abbind<- bind_cols(a,b)

c<-df%>%
filter(study==0)%>%
summarise(study0=paste(round(mean(measure),3), '(', round(sd(measure),3),')', sep=""))

d<- df%>%
filter(study==1)%>%
summarise(study1=paste(round(mean(measure),3), '(', round(sd(measure),3),')', sep=""))

cdbind<- bind_cols(c,d)

e<- df%>%
filter(study==0)%>%
summarise(study0=paste(round((1-(sum(treat)/(nrow(df)-sum(treat)))), 2), sep=""))

f<- df%>%
filter(study==1)%>%
summarise(study1=paste(sum(treat)/sum(study), sep=""))

efbind<- bind_cols(e,f)

fullbind<- rbind(abbind, cdbind, efbind)
colnames(fullbind)<- c("Study 0", "Study 1")
rownames(fullbind)<-c('Age Mean (SD)', 'Measurement Mean (SD)', 'Treatment %')
```

Anyway to refactor this? Thank you guys for all your help!

Comment: Instead of `paste(…, sep = "")` you can use `paste0(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be done with a `group_by` approach instead of `filter`ing each value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
   group_by(study) %>% 
   summarise(Treat = as.character(round(mean(treat))), 
     across(c(age, measure), ~ sprintf('%.2f (%.2f)',
      mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd(., na.rm = TRUE)),
        .names = '{tools::toTitleCase(.col)} Mean (SD)')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -study) %>% 
   mutate(study = str_c('Study ', study)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = study, values_from = value) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('name')
```

-output

```
                       Study 0    Study 1
Treat                        1          1
Age Mean (SD)     35.32 (6.21) 35.30 (NA)
Measure Mean (SD) 35.21 (4.86) 51.22 (NA)
```

-OP's `fullbind` output

```
> fullbind
                            Study 0    Study 1
Age Mean (SD)         35.315(6.207) 35.304(NA)
Measurement Mean (SD)  35.205(4.86) 51.217(NA)
Treatment %                      -1          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(treat = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), study = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), age = c(38.07647, 35.30403, 42.19468, 28.72244, 38.84273, 
28.74006), measure = c(36.36798, 51.21708, 37.71801, 38.84021, 
26.70908, 36.39133)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: The output does not match the table above

Comment: @user16914149 I get the same values for Study0 and STudy 1 based on your example code.  Check the `fullbind`.  The values in the image doesn't match the ones in 'fullbind' as well

Comment: The only change is the negative value in Treatment% for Study 0.  I guess that is because of the way you take the difference

Comment: Got it! Can't figure out what I did wrong with inputting the data frame but i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
summ_table <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(study = paste("Study", study)) %>%
    group_by(study) %>%
    summarize(`Age mean (SD)` = paste(round(mean(age), 3), "(", round(sd(age), 3), ")"),
              `Measurement mean (SD)` = paste(round(mean(measure), 3), "(", round(sd(measure), 3), ")"),
              `Treatment %` = mean(treat)) %>%
    gather("", value, -study) %>% 
    spread(study, value)
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get the table from this? I did kable(summ_table) and got an error about coercing class function to a data.frame

Comment: That would be the expected outcome. You wanted your solution in the form of a function so if you want to kable it you should do kable(summ_table(df)) where df is your raw data